# Converting tile coordinates to pixels to geographic coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, google-maps

There are a lot of similar questions on the web but none of which deals with iOS.

If you have 16 tiles(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1) etc at zoom level 2 (4^N) and the 2 tiles that I am interested in for the United States have tile coordinates of (0,1) and (1,1) both being the standard 256X256 png. These 2 tiles represent precipitation images.

In order to appropriately overlay my precipitation data I would need latitude and longitude coordinates.

[This is a great link](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/) that has taught me quite a bit, but I'm still lost on the coordinate part. In order to get the pixel representation of a map tile ex (1,1) would I multiply both x and y by 256?

I feel like I can do this if I could just figure out the tile map coordinates to pixels to lat/lon values.

Maybe someone could steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I must question why you're doing this calculation manually. There are four methods of `MKMapView` to convert from pixels to coordinates and back. The first two have to do with points:

```
- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
```

Additionally, you can convert rects back and forth:

```
- (CGRect)convertRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region toRectToView:(UIView *)view
- (CGRect)convertRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region toRectToView:(UIView *)view
```

These can all be found in the `MKMapView` reference, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. So essentially a map tile with a coordinate of (1,1) is really just a CGPoint in which I can use that second method to convert it to a 2d coordinate?

Comment: @user1042402: Yes that should work. So, if you take a CGPoint from any view, you can pass it and the view to the map view. Then you'll get a CLLocationCoordinate2D, which is a struct with two values, latitude and longitude. You can then use those values to get your map data. Of course you can also use the first method to get CGPoints from Lat/Lng values.

Answer (score 0):

Well I may have answered one of my questions although I'm not getting the results I thought. By using

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
NSLog(@"Touch point is %f %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
```

I am able to touch points around the map and get the CGPoints back in a log statement. The documentation states that point (0,0) will alway be in the northwest corner according to [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Tile_Overlays)

The actual values I am getting though are (1.00000, 2.00000)(in NW corner). But again, the documentation says at zoom level 0 the map will consist of one big tile and then exponentially increase in respect to the zoom level. I feel like im getting closer to a solution.